# Sample source code to learn spring aop

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I am looking for a sample spring AOP code which I can download and play with. I have read Spring in Action to understand the basic concept on AOP and want to experiment by coding.
I searched https://github.com/SpringSource for AOP examples, could not find one....

Can someone recommend any link?